# Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK debugging problem

Tags: python-3.x, azure, debugging, logging, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to translate a bunch of audio files, which are stored on a local drive, into text.
Now when i do this on my local machine, it works fine. No problem. But when i try executing the same thing on my remote machine (it has the files stored on it, so I don't have to copy to my local machine and back), the service just returns empty files.

The code that I'm using is identical:

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time

import glob
import logging

# ...

# Acquire the logger for a library (azure.storage.blob in this example)
# logger = logging.getLogger('azure.cognitiveservices.speech')
logger = logging.getLogger('azure')

# Set the desired logging level
# logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="azure.log")
logger.addHandler(handler)

root = 'my/root/dir'
audio_root = root + '/audio'
translation_root = root + '/transcription'
list_of_wav_files = glob.glob(audio_root + '/*.wav')
list_of_text_files = glob.glob(translation_root + '/*.txt')
list_of_wav_files = [x[:-4].split('\\')[1] for x in list_of_wav_files]
list_of_text_files = [x[:-4].split('\\')[1] for x in list_of_text_files]

list_of_files_to_convert = set(list_of_wav_files) - set(list_of_text_files)

# Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
# Replace with your own subscription key and region identifier from here: https://aka.ms/speech/sdkregion
speech_key, service_region = "key", "westeurope"

def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file(filename, custom=False):
    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_root + '/' + filename + '.wav')
    if custom:
        speech_config.endpoint_id = "my_custom_endpoint_id"

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config, language="de-DE")

    if custom:
        outFile = open(translation_root + '/' + filename + '_custom_model.txt', 'w')
    else: 
         outFile = open(translation_root + '/' + filename + '.txt', 'w')
    
    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal done
        done = True
        outFile.close()

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: outFile.write('{} \n'.format(evt.result.text)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt.result.text)))
    speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    # </SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>


for file in list_of_files_to_convert:
    print('Converting: ' + file)
    speech_recognize_continuous_from_file(file,  False)
    # speech_recognize_continuous_from_file(file, True)
```

Now when i execute on my local machine, this is the log, that i get:

```
Converting: ID_1
SESSION STARTED: SessionEventArgs(session_id=123)
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=123, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=1212, text="sometext...", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
```

And so on, until it translated the file.

But when i execute the same code on the other machine, i get the following:

```
Converting: ID_1
SESSION STARTED: SessionEventArgs(session_id=1234)
CANCELED SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=1234, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=112, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
CLOSING on SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=1234, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=112, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
SESSION STOPPED SessionEventArgs(session_id=1234)
CLOSING on SessionEventArgs(session_id=1234)
CANCELED SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=1234, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=13, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
CLOSING on SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=1234, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=13, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
```

The log file is also empty.
So i don't know how to debug this problem. My guess is, that the remote machine has a certain port, that needs to be opened. But i can't tell which one, because I don't know which port is being used by the script.
Although if i'm using the requests package, i can successfully call http and https adresses.

As a final note, because that might also lead to the issue:
The local machine is running Windows 10 and the remote Machine is running Windows Server 2016.

Any ideas on why this issue is occurring and how to better debug it, are very welcome.

Comment: You can add a path to a [log file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-logging) for your speech config.
`config.set_property(speechsdk.PropertyId.Speech_LogFilename, "LogfilePathAndName")`
to check for more details. 
Only HTTPS connection is required to connect to the endpoint. Are there any proxy settings on this machine?

Comment: Yes, all trafic should be going through a proxy. Although i found out, that it is directly arriving at the firewall, without any contact to the proxy. After having modified the firewall permissions, the traffic now reaches outside. 
BUT: and this is really weird. 
Still on the local client i get a translation and on the remote client it starts recognizing one word and then abruptly stops.